# Capturing the HTTP requests using .NET

Tags: asp.net

How can I capture all the http requests for a particular URL in .NET?

Comment: what is your exact requirement , you can see all client requests on firebug net panel...for ie you can use fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

you may use HttpContext class in System.Web namespace. refer the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx